# prove a map is uniformly continuous with metric sup

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

> Let $f(x)$ be determined on $C[0,1]$ with metric sup. Check whether
> $f(x)$ is uniformly continuous: $f(x)= x(t_0), t_0\in [0,1]$ is a
> fixed point.

If this function is uniformly continuous, then $\forall\epsilon >0$, there exists a $\delta>0$ such that if the $d(x_1,x_2)<\delta$, then this implies the $d(f(x_1),f(x_2))<\epsilon$.
So we need to find $\delta$ s.t $\forall x,y\in C[0,1], \underset{t\in [0,1]}{\text{sup}}|x(t)-y(t)|<\delta $, then $\underset{t\in [0,1]}{\text{sup}}|f(x(t))-f(y(t))|=\underset{t\in [0,1]}{\text{sup}}|x(t_1)-y(t_2)|=|x(t_1)-y(t_2)|=...<\epsilon $. I don't know how to find such $\delta$. Can someone give me hints?

Comment: If $d(x,y)=\sup_{t\in [0,1]}|x(t)-y(t)|<\epsilon$, then $|f(x)-f(y)|=|x(t_0)-y(t_0)|<\epsilon$.

Comment: What do you mean by $x(t)$? Also, fixed point with respect to what point? There seems to be some details missing.

Answer (score 0):

You question is a bit unclear, but I guess you mean this:

> Consider $t_0 \in [0,1]$ and define
> $$f : C([0,1]) \to \mathbb R, f(x) = x(t_0) .$$
> Show that $f$ is uniformly continuous.

This is easy: If $d_\sup(x,y) = \sup_{t \in [0,1]} \lvert x(t) - y(t) \rvert < \epsilon$, then $\lvert f(x) - f(y) \rvert = \lvert x(t_0)- y(t_0) \rvert \le  \sup_{t \in [0,1]} \lvert x(t) - y(t) \rvert < \epsilon$.